# installing magento sample data on vagrant

Tags: magento-1.9, vagrant

I'm setting up a local Magento 1.9.1 install, using vagrant and [scotch box](https://box.scotch.io/) which I've done multiple times before.

This time however, I've decided to use the sample data package, downloaded from the Magento site.

The sample package includes media and skin folders, which obviously go straight into my Magento directory, and an sql file which I need to import.
The problem I'm having is that I have no idea where in my local file structure I should be placing the sample sql file in order to be able access it from inside my vagrant box. I've tried placing it in ~/my-project-folder/scotch-box/.vagrant but when I 'vagrant ssh' and have a look around I can't see any relation between that folder and the file structure inside the vagrant box. I'm running Linux Mint on my local machine, if that's relevant.

I guess my question could be shortened down to "where on my local machine do the files that make up my vagrant box live, and where do I have to place files on my local machine in order to be able to see them from inside my vagrant box?"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I placed my sql data in the same folder as my vagrantfile and ran

vagrant ssh
sudo updatedb
locate Vagrantfile

this returned /var/www

switching to this directory, I found my sql file waiting for me.